# Computational Complexity and P vs. NP, A New Insight

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, np-complete, proof-techniques, p-vs-np

There is a preprint on arXiv that states (in my own words).

If there are three numbers (digits) and task is to add all three numbers. First we well take two number to add, set aside third number.  Then we will add third number in previous sum of two numbers. So, addition of three number requires two steps, **because we cannot interact and manipulate more than two numbers in single instant**. Our limitation to interact with only two number in single step has played very important role. This is one of reasons why Math axioms involve only two number e.g a.0=0, b.1=b etc…Similarly we cannot sort more than two numbers in single step.  If there is a system that can sort three objects in single step it will be 200% more time efficient.  The kind of sorting that involves three numbers in single step is not possible by humans or man-made machines (not even Turing machines ). But one such system is explained in the paper along with consequences.

The paper concludes

**“It can be stated explicitly that computational complexity appears because of Mathematical Axioms that are constrained by and based on human cognitive limits as human cannot interact with more than two numbers at an instant”**

Is above statement right?

Preprint Link
https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10874

Comment: "Are the claims of this paper correct?" isn't really within the scope of the site. Without carefully reading the paper, it's not really possible to say whether it's correct or not and, although the paper's fairly short, that's still more work than is generally appropriate for a Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: I wouldn't take this "paper" seriously at all.

Comment: @Omar you may, I don't want either, but questions raised in this paper are hard to ignore.

Comment: I don't think so. The author does not even seem aware of the *extended* Church-Turing thesis, let alone that a "third-order comparator" or a "200%" improvement are particularly trivial suggestions/observations.

Comment: but he shows such mechanical systems do exist that can compare three objects without increasing time.

Comment: Sure. Such gates are possible with any constant number of inputs (not just three), and may result in any constant factor speedup. In complexity theory, that's not a big deal. It is very well understood.

Comment: yes, there are system/algorithm that reduce complexity considerably. but is there any system that can sort ten numbers in single step? no. But according to this paper, yes

Comment: And secondly paper says with new set of axioms proofs well require much less steps, same results were shown by Gödel's speed-up theorem

Comment: I have not yet seen research about the cognitive limit for tracking somatic stimuli, but there is a research about visual tracking, which might give some ideas: http://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleid=2121950 Definitely not limited to two, more to be around four, but the upper limit not really detected. Definition for interaction in the OT paper is probably not discussed in deep enough details. Our sensory system is so complex and parallel, just the attention system seems to be very limited. Why would somatic limit be so special compared to other senses, anyway?

Comment: Ten seconds of calculation shows that binary search generalizes to sorting $k$ items at one time step and speeds up by an easily calculable amount. I’m not sure why I should care though, or why this is lauded as being new.

Comment: How can one say that a machine that adds three integers in a row is not physically possible? It’s trivial to build a three way adder circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who says we cannot add three numbers in a single step? We can, and if we use the fastest known methods to add integers, adding three numbers only takes a little bit longer than adding two numbers, not twice as long.

Most modern processors have instructions adding three numbers, for example the LEA (Load Effective Address) instruction on processors based on the Intel architectures.

Answer (score 5):

No.  The paper appears to be total baloney.   I noticed multiple unjustified statements in my first 60 seconds reading the paper.  Don't waste your time with it.

arxiv is not peer-reviewed.  Some papers on arxiv are great; some papers are arxiv are terrible and a waste of time.  Its presence on arxiv says very little about its quality.  It's like finding a paper on someone's personal website.

Comment: The statement still might be right. But it is just not clear from that paper)

Comment: I am fully with you, this is an awkward amateur's work, to speak politely.